# Local Storage Not accessible on Salesforce 1 (Iphone 5 only)

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app

I am trying to set OpportunityID in the local storage for my visualforce lookup page and getting the ID to Parent Page from the Local Storage.
But it seems like on Iphone 5 using Salesforce 1 app not able to get the Id to parent page.
Using IOS 10 and above on Iphone 5.

It works fine on Ipads and Iphone 6 and above.
Dont whats causing the error.

Below is my code :

Setting Id in local storage on Lookup Page:

```
localStorage.setItem("changedOppId",id);
```

Getting Id from Local Storage on Parent page:

```
var IdForOpp = localStorage.getItem("changedOppId");
```

Removing it from Local Storage from Parent page:

```
localStorage.removeItem("changedOppId");
```

Any help is appreciated
Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use platform cache provided by Salesforce?

Comment: @RohitMourya I am using Cache=false on my page as it loads data from cache  when i load the page more than once in a session.That why i am not using cache to store any values.
I am not getting why iphone 5 not supporting local storage while iphone 6 and above supports

Comment: Can't tell exact cause but one possible cause would be if  browsing mode is private then local storage won't work.

Comment: @RohitMourya Checked for the private mode.Its in normal mode still the problem persists .